# ¿Cómo puedo sumar los valores de una fila en un datatable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, datatables

tengo una consulta como puedo sumar los valores de las celdas por fila en un datatable y ponerlos en una nueva columna, agradezco su ayuda de antemano, aquí debajo muestro el código de mi `datatable`.

Lo que quiero es que el valor de ingresos,costo bienes, gastos generales sean sumados y en una nueva columna se muestre el total sumado por fila.

Este el json que va a hacer llamado por el datatable mediante ajax para que se llene el datatable.

listaMantProyectos.json

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "NroCarga": 100005,
            "NroTransferencia": 100005,
            "descripcion_carga": null,
            "descripcion_transf": null,
            "Ingresos": 2.00,
            "descripcionProyecto": null,
            "Sigeri": {
                "Proyecto": null,
                "Colaborador": null,
                "DescPuesto": null,
                "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
                "Horas": 0,
                "TotalCobrado": 0,
                "CostoBienes": 2.00,
                "ManoObra": 2.00,
                "GatosGenerales": 2.00,
                "Depreciacion": 15.00,
                "Tarifa": 0,
                "Validacion": null,
                "CostosTotales": 0
            },
            "DepreciacionId": "1568733322841"
        },
        {
            "NroCarga": 100038,
            "NroTransferencia": 0,
            "descripcion_carga": null,
            "descripcion_transf": null,
            "Ingresos": 32.00,
            "descripcionProyecto": null,
            "Sigeri": {
                "Proyecto": null,
                "Colaborador": null,
                "DescPuesto": null,
                "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
                "Horas": 0,
                "TotalCobrado": 0,
                "CostoBienes": 4.00,
                "ManoObra": 0.00,
                "GatosGenerales": 0.00,
                "Depreciacion": 0.00,
                "Tarifa": 0,
                "Validacion": null,
                "CostosTotales": 0
            },
            "DepreciacionId": "1568739619037"
        },
        {
            "NroCarga": 100122,
            "NroTransferencia": 0,
            "descripcion_carga": null,
            "descripcion_transf": null,
            "Ingresos": 4.00,
            "descripcionProyecto": null,
            "Sigeri": {
                "Proyecto": null,
                "Colaborador": null,
                "DescPuesto": null,
                "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
                "Horas": 0,
                "TotalCobrado": 0,
                "CostoBienes": 4.00,
                "ManoObra": 4.00,
                "GatosGenerales": 4.00,
                "Depreciacion": 70.00,
                "Tarifa": 0,
                "Validacion": null,
                "CostosTotales": 0
            },
            "DepreciacionId": "1568733739782"
        },
        {
            "NroCarga": 100210,
            "NroTransferencia": 0,
            "descripcion_carga": null,
            "descripcion_transf": null,
            "Ingresos": 12.00,
            "descripcionProyecto": null,
            "Sigeri": {
                "Proyecto": null,
                "Colaborador": null,
                "DescPuesto": null,
                "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
                "Horas": 0,
                "TotalCobrado": 0,
                "CostoBienes": 21.00,
                "ManoObra": 21.00,
                "GatosGenerales": 21.00,
                "Depreciacion": 0.00,
                "Tarifa": 0,
                "Validacion": null,
                "CostosTotales": 0
            },
            "DepreciacionId": "1568846197568"
        },
        {
            "NroCarga": 100211,
            "NroTransferencia": 0,
            "descripcion_carga": null,
            "descripcion_transf": null,
            "Ingresos": 21.00,
            "descripcionProyecto": null,
            "Sigeri": {
                "Proyecto": null,
                "Colaborador": null,
                "DescPuesto": null,
                "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
                "Horas": 0,
                "TotalCobrado": 0,
                "CostoBienes": 2.00,
                "ManoObra": 3.00,
                "GatosGenerales": 4.00,
                "Depreciacion": 0.00,
                "Tarifa": 0,
                "Validacion": null,
                "CostosTotales": 0
            },
            "DepreciacionId": "1568846292214"
        },
        {
            "NroCarga": 103546,
            "NroTransferencia": 0,
            "descripcion_carga": null,
            "descripcion_transf": null,
            "Ingresos": 1.00,
            "descripcionProyecto": null,
            "Sigeri": {
                "Proyecto": null,
                "Colaborador": null,
                "DescPuesto": null,
                "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
                "Horas": 0,
                "TotalCobrado": 0,
                "CostoBienes": 1.00,
                "ManoObra": 0.00,
                "GatosGenerales": 0.00,
                "Depreciacion": 6.00,
                "Tarifa": 0,
                "Validacion": null,
                "CostosTotales": 0
            },
            "DepreciacionId": "1568737123144"
        },
        {
            "NroCarga": 103569,
            "NroTransferencia": 0,
            "descripcion_carga": null,
            "descripcion_transf": null,
            "Ingresos": 10.00,
            "descripcionProyecto": null,
            "Sigeri": {
                "Proyecto": null,
                "Colaborador": null,
                "DescPuesto": null,
                "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
                "Horas": 0,
                "TotalCobrado": 0,
                "CostoBienes": 10.00,
                "ManoObra": 10.00,
                "GatosGenerales": 10.00,
                "Depreciacion": 0.00,
                "Tarifa": 0,
                "Validacion": null,
                "CostosTotales": 0
            },
            "DepreciacionId": "1568824943240"
        },
        {
            "NroCarga": 103569,
            "NroTransferencia": 100150,
            "descripcion_carga": null,
            "descripcion_transf": null,
            "Ingresos": 2.00,
            "descripcionProyecto": null,
            "Sigeri": {
                "Proyecto": null,
                "Colaborador": null,
                "DescPuesto": null,
                "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
                "Horas": 0,
                "TotalCobrado": 0,
                "CostoBienes": 2.00,
                "ManoObra": 2.00,
                "GatosGenerales": 2.00,
                "Depreciacion": 0.00,
                "Tarifa": 0,
                "Validacion": null,
                "CostosTotales": 0
            },
            "DepreciacionId": "1568846459043"
        }
    ]
}
```

Código html que crea las cabeceras de la tabla

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 mb-2">
                <div class="">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-bordered"
                        id="tabla_mantProyecto" style="font-size:10px; width:100%">
                        <thead class="alert-primary">
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>N° Carga</th>
                                <th>N° Transferencia</th>
                                <th>Ingresos</th>
                                <th>Costo Bienes</th>
                                <th>Mano Obra</th>
                                <th>Gastos Generales</th>
                                <th>Depreciacion</th>
                                <th>Accion</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tarifaproyecto"></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Este es mi script que carga el datatable

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    MantProyecto.cargar_tabla();

});

var MantProyecto = function(){
    return{
        cargar_tabla() {

                    var table = $("#tabla_mantProyecto").removeAttr('width').DataTable({
                        processing: true,
                        serverSide: false,
                        paging: true,
                        ordering: false,
                        info: true,
                        searching: true,
                        bDestroy: true,
                        autoWidth: false,
                        ajax: {
                            url: 'listaMantProyectos.json',
                            type: 'GET',
                            datatype: "json"
                        },
                        columns: [
                            {
                                data: null,
                                orderable: false
                            },
                            { data: "NroCarga", orderable: false },
                            { data: "NroTransferencia", orderable: false },
                            { data: "Ingresos", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, 'S/. '), orderable: false },
                            { data: "Sigeri.CostoBienes", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, 'S/. '), orderable: false },
                            { data: "Sigeri.ManoObra", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, 'S/. '), orderable: false },
                            { data: "Sigeri.GatosGenerales", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, 'S/. '), orderable: false },
                            { data: "Sigeri.Depreciacion", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, 'S/. '), orderable: false },
                            {
                                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                                    //return '<a class="btn btn-info" href="javascript: tarifa.fnEditarProyecto(' + full.Proyecto.IdProyecto + ');" title="Editar registro.">Editar</a>';
                                    return '<button  class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="btnEditar" onClick="MantProyecto.fnEditarMantProyecto(' + full.DepreciacionId + ')">Editar</button >' +
                                        '<button  class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="btnEliminar" onClick="MantProyecto.fnEliminarMantProyecto(' + full.DepreciacionId + ')">Eliminar</button >';
                                },

                            },

                            // { data: "Tarifa", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, 'S/. ') },

                        ],
                        columnDefs: [
                            {
                                sortable: false,
                                "class": "index",
                                targets: 0
                            },
                            { width: "150", targets: 3 }
                        ],
                        language: {
                            "decimal": "",
                            "emptyTable": "No hay información",
                            "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Entradas",
                            "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Entradas",
                            "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
                            "infoPostFix": "",
                            "thousands": ",",
                            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Entradas",
                            "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                            "processing": "Procesando...",
                            "search": "Buscar:",
                            "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
                            "paginate": {
                                "first": "Primero",
                                "last": "Ultimo",
                                "next": "Siguiente",
                                "previous": "Anterior"
                            }
                        }

                    });

                    table.on('order.dt search.dt', function () {
                        table.column(0, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
                            cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
                        });
                    }).draw();

                }
    }
}();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entendí bien, lo haría de esta forma entonces:

```
var data = {
"data": [
    {
        "NroCarga": 100005,
        "NroTransferencia": 100005,
        "descripcion_carga": null,
        "descripcion_transf": null,
        "Ingresos": 2.00,
        "descripcionProyecto": null,
        "Sigeri": {
            "Proyecto": null,
            "Colaborador": null,
            "DescPuesto": null,
            "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
            "Horas": 0,
            "TotalCobrado": 0,
            "CostoBienes": 2.00,
            "ManoObra": 2.00,
            "GatosGenerales": 2.00,
            "Depreciacion": 15.00,
            "Tarifa": 0,
            "Validacion": null,
            "CostosTotales": 0
        },
        "DepreciacionId": "1568733322841"
    },
    {
        "NroCarga": 100038,
        "NroTransferencia": 0,
        "descripcion_carga": null,
        "descripcion_transf": null,
        "Ingresos": 32.00,
        "descripcionProyecto": null,
        "Sigeri": {
            "Proyecto": null,
            "Colaborador": null,
            "DescPuesto": null,
            "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
            "Horas": 0,
            "TotalCobrado": 0,
            "CostoBienes": 4.00,
            "ManoObra": 0.00,
            "GatosGenerales": 0.00,
            "Depreciacion": 0.00,
            "Tarifa": 0,
            "Validacion": null,
            "CostosTotales": 0
        },
        "DepreciacionId": "1568739619037"
    },
    {
        "NroCarga": 100122,
        "NroTransferencia": 0,
        "descripcion_carga": null,
        "descripcion_transf": null,
        "Ingresos": 4.00,
        "descripcionProyecto": null,
        "Sigeri": {
            "Proyecto": null,
            "Colaborador": null,
            "DescPuesto": null,
            "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
            "Horas": 0,
            "TotalCobrado": 0,
            "CostoBienes": 4.00,
            "ManoObra": 4.00,
            "GatosGenerales": 4.00,
            "Depreciacion": 70.00,
            "Tarifa": 0,
            "Validacion": null,
            "CostosTotales": 0
        },
        "DepreciacionId": "1568733739782"
    },
    {
        "NroCarga": 100210,
        "NroTransferencia": 0,
        "descripcion_carga": null,
        "descripcion_transf": null,
        "Ingresos": 12.00,
        "descripcionProyecto": null,
        "Sigeri": {
            "Proyecto": null,
            "Colaborador": null,
            "DescPuesto": null,
            "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
            "Horas": 0,
            "TotalCobrado": 0,
            "CostoBienes": 21.00,
            "ManoObra": 21.00,
            "GatosGenerales": 21.00,
            "Depreciacion": 0.00,
            "Tarifa": 0,
            "Validacion": null,
            "CostosTotales": 0
        },
        "DepreciacionId": "1568846197568"
    },
    {
        "NroCarga": 100211,
        "NroTransferencia": 0,
        "descripcion_carga": null,
        "descripcion_transf": null,
        "Ingresos": 21.00,
        "descripcionProyecto": null,
        "Sigeri": {
            "Proyecto": null,
            "Colaborador": null,
            "DescPuesto": null,
            "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
            "Horas": 0,
            "TotalCobrado": 0,
            "CostoBienes": 2.00,
            "ManoObra": 3.00,
            "GatosGenerales": 4.00,
            "Depreciacion": 0.00,
            "Tarifa": 0,
            "Validacion": null,
            "CostosTotales": 0
        },
        "DepreciacionId": "1568846292214"
    },
    {
        "NroCarga": 103546,
        "NroTransferencia": 0,
        "descripcion_carga": null,
        "descripcion_transf": null,
        "Ingresos": 1.00,
        "descripcionProyecto": null,
        "Sigeri": {
            "Proyecto": null,
            "Colaborador": null,
            "DescPuesto": null,
            "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
            "Horas": 0,
            "TotalCobrado": 0,
            "CostoBienes": 1.00,
            "ManoObra": 0.00,
            "GatosGenerales": 0.00,
            "Depreciacion": 6.00,
            "Tarifa": 0,
            "Validacion": null,
            "CostosTotales": 0
        },
        "DepreciacionId": "1568737123144"
    },
    {
        "NroCarga": 103569,
        "NroTransferencia": 0,
        "descripcion_carga": null,
        "descripcion_transf": null,
        "Ingresos": 10.00,
        "descripcionProyecto": null,
        "Sigeri": {
            "Proyecto": null,
            "Colaborador": null,
            "DescPuesto": null,
            "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
            "Horas": 0,
            "TotalCobrado": 0,
            "CostoBienes": 10.00,
            "ManoObra": 10.00,
            "GatosGenerales": 10.00,
            "Depreciacion": 0.00,
            "Tarifa": 0,
            "Validacion": null,
            "CostosTotales": 0
        },
        "DepreciacionId": "1568824943240"
    },
    {
        "NroCarga": 103569,
        "NroTransferencia": 100150,
        "descripcion_carga": null,
        "descripcion_transf": null,
        "Ingresos": 2.00,
        "descripcionProyecto": null,
        "Sigeri": {
            "Proyecto": null,
            "Colaborador": null,
            "DescPuesto": null,
            "TarifaPromedioxPerfil": 0,
            "Horas": 0,
            "TotalCobrado": 0,
            "CostoBienes": 2.00,
            "ManoObra": 2.00,
            "GatosGenerales": 2.00,
            "Depreciacion": 0.00,
            "Tarifa": 0,
            "Validacion": null,
            "CostosTotales": 0
        },
        "DepreciacionId": "1568846459043"
    }
]
}
```

Y la sumatoria la haría de esta manera:

```
data.data.forEach(function(item,index){ 
    item.suma=0; 
    item.suma += item.Ingresos; 
    item.suma += (item.Sigeri.CostoBienes + item.Sigeri.GatosGenerales);
    console.log(item.suma) 
})
```

Por cada objeto en el arreglo se crea una nueva propiedad llamada suma.